# Linking user accounts to primary key values in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Im brand new to Apex and fairly new to SQL. I made a database that has teachers and students. I want to make an oracle apex application such that when teachers make a new course students can sign up to it. However, since there are many teachers how do i make a form in Apex so that it knows what teacher i am referring to? I wouldnt expect teachers to have to enter their teacher_id (primary key) but dont know what to do.

I made a sequence and trigger so that when a teacher makes a new course listing, a new row goes to the database. What i am stuck on is how apex can identify which teacher is posting that. I have tried to make different users as well but have no idea how to link a teacher user account on apex to a teacher_id (primary key) value in my database so that whenever a specific teacher logs into the apex application, the database knows their teacher_id and uses that automatically whenever a teacher_id is required.

Any form of guidance will be helpful (even a link to a useful youtube video that addresses my problem - I have searched to no avail thus far).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option would be to identify teachers (and students) by their *usernames* (they use to log in into your Apex application). In Apex, it is then referenced as `:APP_USER` variable. As there can't be duplicates (obviously), it will be unique so there won't be any confusion.

So, alter the *users* table and - along with their ID (which you already have) - add the `USERNAME` column (or `APP_USER`, or whatever you want to name it).

Comment: Also, could you please expand on how i can use this app_user notion because im not sure how to implement it. i added a username and password column to my teacher table so teachers log in with a username and password now. however when a teacher views teacher details they can see the details of every teacher but they should only see their own. im guessing i need a dynamic action on page load of teacher details that somehow only shows the information of the teacher currently logged on (which is proablly where the app_user comes in) but im not sure how this would work.

Comment: Ive made a new question about this by the way since im not sure if stack overflow gives you a notification when i comment on your post

Comment: You'd apply a WHERE clause to all queries you use, e.g. `where username = :APP_USER` or `where teacher_id = (select teacher_id from my_users where username = :APP_USER)`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information that you have provided, I gather that you have got the tables for the teacher in place. Also, I understand that this table has a primary key of teacher_id.

Now in the course creation form, you can have a field that is mapped to this primary_key column. For display purposes, you can make this field resolve the teacher name (instead of the teacher_id) value. You can achieve this by associating the field with a List of Values (either via a Shared Component).

There are multiple configuration options to achieve this. Here is a link to help you get started on this.
[Oracle Apex - LoVs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/htmdb/creating-lists-of-values-at-the-application-level.html#GUID-97D8B5E5-3D83-4C3D-8BF8-C1B38E4AA1CF)

Once, you have the field render user-friendly data, if you would like it to be auto-populated based on the logged in user, you can take the approach that @Littlefoot has suggested above and link the `:APP_USER` with the teacher_id and use that to set the default value into this field.

Comment: Hi, ive made a new question regarding this app user i hope you can see